# Pointer to forward Declared Template Class

Tags: templates, c++11

i have created a simple template based class. now i am trying to write a stream reader & writer. i just want a pointer to array in stream. but it dose not work.
i am using VS2015

```
////////////////////////////Array.h
#include "Stream.h"

template<typename... Types> class TArray {};

template<typename T0> class TArray<T0>
{
    friend Stream& << (Stream& stream, const TArray& arr)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}


///////////////////////////////Stream.h
class Stream
{
public:
    class TArray<char>* mArray; //ERROR, it dose not work
}
```

Comment: You need to forward declare TArray template class in Stream.h file.

Comment: template<typename T0> class TArray<T0> {...}
is not a concrete class and does not generate any machine code.

TArray<char> is one and the correct syntax of mArray declaration should be:
...
TArray<char>* mArray; 
...

friend functions are declarations inside a class and not definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
template< typename T0 > class TArray
{
    friend Stream& << (Stream& stream, const TArray& arr)
    {
```

to declare template for arbitrary T0 class. 
Or:

```
template<> class TArray< T0 >
{
    friend Stream& << (Stream& stream, const TArray< T0 >& arr)
    {
```

to declare specification of the template declared earlier for specific class T0. T0 mast be known already defined class, for instance char in your case.